# ZXing BarcodeReader.cs not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bitmap, barcode, zxing

I'm trying to use this library on an ASP .NET MVC4 project.

Here is part of the code:

```
using ZXing.QrCode;
using ZXing.Common;
using ZXing;

...

public string getIDQR(Bitmap bitmap) {
        try
        {
            BarcodeReader q = new BarcodeReader();
            q.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
            q.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
            q.AutoRotate = false;
            q.TryHarder = false;

            // Decode result
            string r = q.Decode(bitmap).Text;

            return r;
        }
        catch {
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
```

I'm getting a BarcodeReader.cs not found error. I would appreciate some help! Thanks!

Comment: How did you add zxing to your project? Did you add the source code of the library manually or did you set a reference to the assembly? The error message points to a problem with a zxing project file which you added to your solution but you haven't placed the source code file BarcodeReader.cs at the right place.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for answering. I searched in the NuGet package manager and then I "installed it" to the project. It added two references to the project: zxing and zxing.presentation. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If it helps, I found out that for some reason the class is being searched at D:\Entwicklung\Tools\Internet\ZXing.Net.Build.4\Source\lib\BarcodeReader.cs That is not my machine..

Comment: That's the path from my machine because I built the package. But now I have an idea what's wrong. Is the error which you got a build error or a runtime error? I think it is a runtime error. Correct me if I'm wrong. At runtime it isn't the real error. I think the "not found error" comes from the debugger. There should be another exception which is hidden. Please look carefully in the output windows and post the complete error here.

Comment: @Michael It is a debug error. I get it when I'm debugging this instruction:
BarcodeReader q = new BarcodeReader();

Here's a pic of what I'm getting.

[Error Image](http://i.imgur.com/l0qG9mb.png).

Sorry about the spanish, tell me if it isn't clear, and I'll translate.

Comment: Please ignore this debug error. It is normal because you don't have the source files on your machine. Please look for the real error which occured right before.

Comment: The library is just working fine. Not runtime errors. I was trying to correct other bugs, and when I was debugging appeared that error I mentioned. It seems there is not any runtime error. Thanks for your help and time!